# In Symfony, how do I translate an associated field (foreign key) in an entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, translation, sonata

I have an *Event* entity containing a *gallery*. There should be different galleries per *locale*. I applied here the same *Translatable* annotation from my *title* string:

```
 use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
 use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Model\Gedmo\TranslatableInterface;
 use Sonata\TranslationBundle\Traits\Gedmo\PersonalTranslatableTrait;    

 /** other codes hidden for brevity **/

/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="events")
* @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="App\Entity\Translation\EventTranslation")
*/
class Event implements TranslatableInterface {
   use PersonalTranslatableTrait;

   /** other fields hidden for brevity **/

   /**
    * @var Gallery $gallery
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery", cascade={"persist"})
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gallery_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete = "SET NULL")
    * })
    * 
    * @Gedmo\Translatable()
    */
   private $gallery;
```

But on refresh, I'm getting:

**InvalidMappingException**
**Unable to find translatable [gallery] as mapped property in entity - App\Entity\Event**

By the way, the title string and other translatable strings worked correctly (i.e. entries are created in event_translations tables without errors)

So, for example, the default locale (en) and other locales (ph, wb)

My expected result is something like this:

```
table: event
----------------------------------
id  |   title       |   gallery_id
23  |   my event    |   451
----------------------------------

table: event_translations
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  |locale |object_class       |field      |foreign_key    |content
1   |ph     |App\Entity\Event   |title      |23             |aking piyesta
2   |ph     |App\Entity\Event   |gallery    |23             |452
3   |wb     |App\Entity\Event   |gallery    |23             |453
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The title translation row is already correct.
I just want the same logic to apply to the gallery too.

Comment: Do you have implemented Translatable ?

Ex. class Article implements Translatable { content } and defined  Gedmo\Translatable\Translatable in use section ?

Comment: @3y3skill3r Yes, the normal translations work properly, e.g. for string title. I hid some parts of my code.

Comment: @3y3skill3r Please see my updated code above

Comment: I don't understand. What's the expected result? One Event has several distinct Gallery entities tagged with the locale? One Event has as a single gallery but something will translate it somehow depending on the locale? What do you picture your table should look like?

Comment: @NicolasB I have updated my question with more details above. Basically, my expected result is one Event will have several distinct Gallery entities tagged with the locale

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work.

The translation class should be something like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="event_translation")
 */
class EventTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Event", inversedBy="translations")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $object;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Gallery")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gallery_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $gallery;
}
```

and the Event class would be:

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EventRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="events")
* @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="App\Entity\Translation\EventTranslation")
*/
class OrderEntity implements TranslatableInterface
{
    use PersonalTranslatableTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Translation\EventTranslation", mappedBy="object", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Gedmo\Translatable()
     */
    private $translations;

    // ...

}
```

so that the gallery is a field of the EventTranslation and not a field of the Event directly.

Let me know how it goes.